# Set writeTimeout for Tomcat NioChannel

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat

How can I set the writeTimeout for Tomcat Responses? More specificially I mean the `writeTimeout`-field in the `KeyAttachment`s of an NioChannel, which is used, when writing a chunk to the Socket and defaults to infinite, which is not suitable for my use case. I can only find information on how to set read-timeouts or the connectionTimeout.

The code, which uses the writeTimeout from the KeyAttachment, is found here: http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-core/8.0.24/org/apache/coyote/http11/InternalNioOutputBuffer.java#129

```
NioEndpoint.KeyAttachment att = (NioEndpoint.KeyAttachment)socket.getAttachment();
if ( att == null ) throw new IOException("Key must be cancelled");
long writeTimeout = att.getWriteTimeout();
```

The motivation for this question is from this question: [Spring StreamingResponseBody Request Thread not cleaned up, when client closes connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42981008/spring-streamingresponsebody-request-thread-not-cleaned-up-when-client-closes-c)

Comment: There is no such thing as a write timeout in NIO, and, if there was, it wouldn't be done via the key attachment.

Comment: I edited the question and added the code, which uses the writeTimeout from the KeyAttachment. So there is a writeTimeout. My question is, how can I customize it?